# While I use Chinese in the Android Things the text becomes garbled

Tags: android-things

[image]

The text becomes garbled when I use Chinese characters on Android Things device.

Comment: which encoding do you use?

Comment: I use utf-8 to encode

Comment: Can you give us some more information, some code etc.

Comment: I just use the Chinese like"你好" in a TextView，it will be garbled like the picture above

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a font which supports the chinese characters:

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
myText.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "DroidSans.ttf"));
```

The *DroidSans.tff* file needs to be placed in the assets folder.

Comment: Have you checked of the sign is contained in the `DroidSans.ttf`?

Comment: Is the problem only with this character or also with other characters?

Comment: this problem just occurred in the new Android things OS

Answer (score 0):

I solve this way.

## code

```
TextView txtHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_hello);
txtHello.setTypeface(ResourceCompat.getFont(context, R.font.nanum);
```

## resource

[image: font file location]